# How to drop sql server database that has not been logged in for over 30 days

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 SQL Server instances running on 3 different servers. I want to be able to automatically drop any database that has not been logged in for more than 30 days.I am trying to do this in power-shell see below code:

```
$SQLInstances = "sql2016", "sql2014", "sql2012"

$SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM sys.databases  WHERE name not in  ('tempdb','model', 'msdb', 'master','EVN') and name not like '%report%'"

foreach($sqLInstance in $SQLInstances) {

    $ListOfDatabases = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqLInstance -Database "master" -Query $SQLQuery

    ForEach ($Database in $ListOfDatabases ) {

    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqLInstance -Database "$Database" -Query "IF (SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE DATEDIFF(day, LOGIN_TIME , GETDATE()) > 30 ) 

        BEGIN

        DROP DATABASE $Database

        END "

    }


}
```

I'm getting stuck on how to drop the databases. The last thing I would need is to send an email with a list of databases that will be/have been dropped.

Any suggestions on how my code should be like?

Comment: Just curious, what is the reasoning behind this? Do you have multiple users creating their own databases for their individual purposes on a shared server?

Comment: @KamilGosciminski Yes, my organisation is big and multiple users create their own databases and sometimes they forget to cleanup after themselves. I end up running out of space because some databases have not been used for years

Comment: Consider switching to schemas for different users, instead of databases. Not sure if you thought about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact thing you need is mentioned in this article.

You can find the no used DB based on the number of connections and the login time.

You can schedule it as a SQL Job, so you do not need external scheduling and powershell to manage it.

There is option to send email from within Stored Procudure. You just need to configure the SMTP details for the outgoing EMail.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3171/identify-sql-server-databases-that-are-no-longer-in-use/